# How to put Twilio call on hold

Tags: php, twilio-php

I am trying to implement following on Twilio, but not sure why I am not able to get it done correctly. I have initiated a call using standard Twilio procedures from `twilio.device.connect`. After a call is initiated, I am updating the call to new url in order to put it on hold.

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($accountSid, $authToken); 
$call = $client->account->calls->get($call_sid); 
$call->update( 
    array( 
        "Url"    => "http://localhost/voice.xml",               
        "Method" => "POST",  
    )
);
```

Now here instead of putting end user on hold it just disconnects the call, and play music on my side. Why it is happening?

Comment: Why not use TwiML? Also are you initiating the call via the JS client? If so the APP associated with this should point to and endpoint containing some XML where you could execute your hold functionality.

Comment: yes this is what I am doing but it just disconnect call

Comment: Looking at your code that is not TwiML, you are using the REST API. Where is your TwiML?

Answer (score 0):

No the issue is because there are two legs of the call. Look in the call logs. You need to get the other leg of the call. Twilio doesn't seem to allow us to see the subcalls via the API but the public API (via the console does get them).

So instead you need to get all calls and filter where the parent of the call is your call sid.

So when placing someone on hold, get all calls where the parent call sid is the callSid you have. Then use the callSid of the child that has your call as the parent.

I would like to be able to get the sub calls from the call instance we have but I don't see how that is possible.

```js
  public async enqueueCall(callSid: string, queueName: string): Promise<CallInstance> {
    const call = await this.getCall(callSid);
    console.log({ backendCall: call });

    const correctedCallSid = await this.getCustomersCallSid(call);

    return await this.client.calls(correctedCallSid).update({
      twiml: `<Response><Enqueue>${queueName}</Enqueue></Response>`,
    });
  }

  private async getCustomersCallSid({
    parentCallSid,
    direction,
    sid,
  }: CallInstance): Promise<string> {
    if (parentCallSid === null && direction === "inbound") {
      const childCall = await this.client.calls.list({ parentCallSid: sid });

      // If call is a child and it is inbound then it is actually an outbound call
      if (childCall.length) {
        console.log({ childCall });
        return childCall[0].sid;
      }

      // If the call is not a child and it is inbound then it is actually an dequeued call
      return sid;
    }

    if (parentCallSid !== null && direction === "outbound-dial") {
      // IF the call does have a parent and it is outbound-dial then it is actually an inbound call
      return parentCallSid;
    }

    return sid;
  }
```

Here's how I had to do it.

1. If I am dialing out. Then direction is 'inbound' -.- and there is another call that has parentSid equal to my current calls id. Therefore we want to get that other call and use its sid.
2. If I am dequeuing a customer via device.connect() and giving the queues name or sid. Then there is NOT a child but that calls till has a parent.
3. Otherwise if someone is calling me directly then just use `sid`.

Horrible, confusing and poorly documented.

Answer (score -1):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest checking to see if Twilio is logging any errors:

https://www.twilio.com/user/account/monitor/alerts

If you are trying to redirect Twilio to "http://localhost", thats not going to work because Twilio obviously does not know how to reach the localhost running on your own machine.

If you want to expose a web server running on your own local machine to the internet via a public URL check out an awesome tool called [ngrok](http://ngrok.com).

Comment: no I am not using localhost, it is public url, but when I execute above code, it start hold music for me, instead of end user and for end user it just disconnect call in between

Answer (score -1):

the reason is that after the `<Play>` tag in your
"http://localhost/voice.xml" file.. **there is no  further TwiML that gets executed.**

The solution is to **redirect the call back to its original state**.