# How can I put a twilio call on hold without conference?

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

We are developing a calling web app using React and Node. In this app, we are providing incoming and outgoing calls. But I am having trouble holding the hold. Please provide some references or code.

I want to put the call on hold without conference and then play music on the other end.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This stackexchange post might offer a viable solution: [Place a Twilio call on hold and retrieve it later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345222/place-a-twilio-call-on-hold-and-retrieve-it-later)

Answer (score 0):

No the issue is because there are two legs of the call. Look in the call logs. You need to get the other leg of the call. Twilio doesn't seem to allow us to see the subcalls via the API but the public API (via the console does get them).

So instead you need to get all calls and filter where the parent of the call is your call sid.

So when placing someone on hold, get all calls where the parent call sid is the callSid you have. Then use the callSid of the child that has your call as the parent.

I would like to be able to get the sub calls from the call instance we have but I don't see how that is possible.

```js
  public async enqueueCall(callSid: string, queueName: string): Promise<CallInstance> {
    const call = await this.getCall(callSid);
    console.log({ backendCall: call });

    const correctedCallSid = await this.getCustomersCallSid(call);

    return await this.client.calls(correctedCallSid).update({
      twiml: `<Response><Enqueue>${queueName}</Enqueue></Response>`,
    });
  }

  private async getCustomersCallSid({
    parentCallSid,
    direction,
    sid,
  }: CallInstance): Promise<string> {
    if (parentCallSid === null && direction === "inbound") {
      const childCall = await this.client.calls.list({ parentCallSid: sid });

      // If call is a child and it is inbound then it is actually an outbound call
      if (childCall.length) {
        console.log({ childCall });
        return childCall[0].sid;
      }

      // If the call is not a child and it is inbound then it is actually an dequeued call
      return sid;
    }

    if (parentCallSid !== null && direction === "outbound-dial") {
      // IF the call does have a parent and it is outbound-dial then it is actually an inbound call
      return parentCallSid;
    }

    return sid;
  }
```

Here's how I had to do it.

1. If I am dialing out. Then direction is 'inbound' -.- and there is another call that has parentSid equal to my current calls id. Therefore we want to get that other call and use its sid.
2. If I am dequeuing a customer via device.connect() and giving the queues name or sid. Then there is NOT a child but that calls till has a parent.
3. Otherwise if someone is calling me directly then just use `sid`.

Horrible, confusing and poorly documented. To be clear, this uses twilio-node and lives on the backend. You call it from your frontend. You will need to know the name of the queue you want to put them into.

To ensure I can put two people on hold at the SAME TIME, I use the currently logged in users `email+5 random characters`. Otherwise you can only dequeue the oldest call due to it being `FIFO`.